# Vector algebra and applications

Tags: vectors

Can anyone explain the collinearity and coplanarity of vectors ?
I'm stuck with the relation between linear dependence, coplanarity, collinearity.

Answer (score 0):

Given a collection of vectors $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ the *dimension* of the space spanned by those vectors is the minimal number of vectors needed to form a basis for that space.  One common technique in finding the dimension or finding the basis (*at least for finite-dimensional vector spaces*) is row reduction.

A collection of vectors $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ are said to be *colinear* if the space they span is one-dimensional (*or less*).

A collection of vectors $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ are said to be *coplanar* if the space they span is two-dimensional (*or less*).

Note that any collection of three or more vectors must be linearly dependent if they were to also be colinear or coplanar, but being colinear or coplanar is a stronger more specific condition than simply being dependent.  A collection of two vectors is always coplanar regardless of linear independence.

Comment: could you be some more specific about their applications?

Comment: "*Be more specific about their applications*"... To me that sounds like asking "What are the applications of knowing that I can color a picture using just two colors if I wanted"... the obvious application being that I can use only two colors instead of several...  If I know that a collection of vectors are coplanar then I can describe the space they span using only two vectors.  Is that useful to do?  That depends on what you're doing.